# HTML entities error Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple contact form on a Laravel 5.2 install. Whenever I go to send the email I get the error

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

I have narrowed it down to my text area for the message. If I remove it from the email view I have no issue.

Contact.blade.php

```
<section>
                            <label class="label">Message</label>
                            <label class="textarea">
                                <i class="icon-append fa fa-comment"></i>
                                <textarea rows="4" name="message" id="message">{{ old('message') }}</textarea>
                            </label>
                        </section>
```

Contact_email.blade.php

```
Name: {{ $name }}<br>
Email: {{ $email }}<br>
Subject: {{ $subject }}<br>
Message: {{ $message }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change variable name to a `themessage`. It can be conflict of variable names.